# Conditional formatting 1 cell based on cell input on another sheet, apply to entire row

Tags: conditional-formatting, excel-2016

For work I need to create a resource management excel file. My goal is to create an overview as is seen here:

[image]

If John would have taken a few hours off, or if he has a fey hours of sick leave, I would like to turn **this cell only** to change colour so I know that John will be absent for whatever reason on this day.

However, since I'm creating this for an entire row (for a whole year), I do not want to create conditional formatting per cell because that would be plain madness.

Here is an example per employee (in this example John):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVXrB.png)

So what I need is a formula to check if a cell in a row (for example sick leave) on the employee worksheet is grater than 0 and then change the colour of **only** the corresponding cell on the recourse planning worksheet, **not** the entire row.

Does any of you guys know if this is possible in excel 2016? Preferably without VBA scripting since I have to transfer this excel file to a co-worker who is not into VBA programming.

Thank in advance.

Nuntius transmittendus!

Comment: see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBMj--NjWt4)

Comment: This changes colour or the entire row. I want it to look in an entire row in the John worksheet and change a corresponding cell on the recourse planning. So if John!C4>0 change Recourse planning!C4 to blue. But I need the formula to do this for the entire row 4, 5, 6 and 7 on the John worksheet and apply it to only row 4 in the resource planning worksheet.

Comment: you can use `COUNTIFS` to count how many times something occurs in a row

Comment: I don't think I understand where you are going with this. How does `COUNTIFS`  help me exactly? Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry I thought you are actually looking for something complex. Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/c4nGa0N.png) what you are looking for ?

Comment: No I'm sorry that's not it. Lets say John calls in sick on Tuesday 5th of march, and I add 8 hours of sick leave on the **John sheet**. I would like Tuesday 5th of march behind John's name on the **recourse planning sheet** to change colour, indicating that there is something special with John on that day. So I need a formula that can do that for me. But I need one formula that looks at the entire row and changes the cell colour only of the cell that represents Tuesday.

Comment: I understand resource planning but I'm not gonna do the whole thing for you. I pointed you towards something you can use, I don't owe you an answer. If I see you tried to use what I advised and you have a **specific** problem I will help you further. Also [resource](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=61yGXIjKDrGRmwWS3bOgBw&q=recourse&btnK=Google+Search&oq=recourse&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i10l9.379.1742..1846...1.0..0.192.1202.1j8......0....1..gws-wiz.....0.yb5FJ70gfXs) is spelled **resource**.

Comment: I understand you won't do the whole thing I figured my explanation was not clear enough. Mind you, I really do appreciate you putting time in to it. And I'm not waiting for someone to hand me the answer without working on it myself. `COUNTIFS` returns a number of cells but I am not able to put it to use because I can't link it to a specific cell. The greater than value does work but also only per cell. I tried various things like `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP` unfortunately without success. But I will keep looking for a solution that works.

Comment: You need to make a formula that returns `TRUE` for whatever conditions you've set. Then you need to use that formula like the guy in the video I linked. I'm reluctant to help because 1) I don't see the "John" sheet 2) maybe you can change the design of the workbook to make it easier for yourself, think about it

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible without any code.  Use `CountIf()` as tinus087 commented.  The tricky part is how to create the address range used by the `CountIf()` so that you can put one conditional format on all the cells.  On the the one hand you need the column of the cells being checked to match the column of your total cell.  On the other hand the worksheet tab name needs to change depending on which row you are on. So use `INDIRECT()` to point to the correct worksheet and `OFFSET()` to look at the correct cells.

So, for cell C4, the formula you want to use as the range in your `CountIf()` is `OFFSET(INDIRECT($A4&"!A1"),3,COLUMN(C1)-1,4)`.  When applied to cell C4 this creates address John!C4:C7.  When used for cell D4, it results in John!D4:D7.

You'll probably want some error checking to deal with the `#REF!` error happens when the formula is applied to a row without a first name or where the name listed doesn't match any worksheet tabs.

Something else to think about, if you haven't already, what happens if there are two John's?  Is the 2nd John going to be named John2?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will start working on it. For the record: @reportgunner was the one suggesting the `COUNTIFS` statement. :)

Comment: Almost there, I changed the code a bit because I want to check the rows not the columns. I also had to change `,` to `;` in order to get it working. Not sure what causes this. Thanks for the `INDIRECT` statement, that's brilliant. What to do when we have two Johns... I don't know fire 1 of them? ;) I now have: `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A4&"!A1");3;COLUMN(C1)-1;;7);">0")`  But if I add any integer on the John sheet on Friday, it changes the colour on the resource planning sheet from Monday till Friday. Is there any add-on to filter out the cells that should not be affected? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I changed the code again to include the first and last name as follows: `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT($A4&"_"&$B4&"!A1");3;COLUMN(C1)-1;;7);">0")`. I changed the sheet name to John_Smith. Now the likelihood of two identically named persons will be less. Still working on the colouring issue though.